# Determine number of installed TS cals

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

How can I determine how many simultaneous remote desktop / remote app users can use a particular host? 
Is there a better way of scripting the current amount of users logged on other than fetching the output of "qwinsta" (like WMI etc)

Answer (score 1):

TS Device CALs:

```
 lsreport.exe /F c:\report.txt [TSLicServerName1], [TSLicServerName1], …
```

Windows Server Resource Kit

TS User CALs:

```
cscript //Nologo PerUserCALReport.vbs /W2K3 [domainFQDN]
```

TechNet Script Center

GUI:

```
lsview
```

Count session:

```
query session /counter|find /i "sessions"
```

Comment: The machine is not on a domain, and leaving that argument out when executing "PerUserCALReport.vbs" have the script fail, stating that no domain was found.